# Print 3D array converted into a 2D

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, integer

I am trying to add a given 3D array and print it as D. Moreover, I have to take the array[0] and [1] from a given 3d Array and add their corresponding positions in a 2D Array an add them.

For example, if a 3D Array has the following 2D Matrices

```
> Array[0] : {1,2,3},
>    
>            {4,5,6}
> 
> 
> Array[1] :  {1,1,1},
> 
>             {1,1,1}
```

The 2D Array should print

```
     {2,3,4},
>    
>            {5,6,7}
```

This is my code. However, it gives the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at ThreeDRay.add(ThreeDRay.java:53)
    at ThreeDRayRunner.main(ThreeDRayRunner.java:53)
```

Line `53` is:

```
for (int j=0; j<b[j].length;j++)
```

But I don't know whats wrong with it:

```
public static void add(int[][][]array){

        int [][] b = new int[array[0].length][array[0][0].length];

        for (int x=0; x<array.length;x++){
            for (int y=0; y<array[0].length;y++){
                for (int z=0; z<array[0][0].length;z++){
                    b[y][z] += array[x][y][z];
                }
            }
        }

    System.out.println ("Adding matrix at 0 and matrix at 1 ");

    for (int i=0; i<b.length;i++){
            for (int j=0; j<b[j].length;j++){
                System.out.print(b[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
for (int j=0; j<b[j].length;j++)
{
  System.out.print(b[i][j]);
}
```

Here you are taking `b[j]` length which can potentially go out of bounds, because you are taking different array later (`b[i]`). Just do `b[i].length` in that `for` loop and it should fix it. Remember that `for` loop is checking the condition before every iteration, not just at creation.

Comment: I changed it to :  
 for (int i=0; i<b.length;i++)
  {
   
   for (int j=0; j<b[i].length;j++)
   {
    System.out.print(b[i][j]);
   }
   System.out.println();
  }
 }                                                                                                             However, it still doesnt work @Whatzs